# VS 2010 Database Project deploy sql scripts

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, deployment

I am working on a sql database project in VS 2010. I know how to synchronize the schema, but what I want is this:
1. I have some data sql scripts that inserts data into some tables.
2. I want to when I click Deploy on the DB project to automatically deploy those data scripts and execute them on the sql server.

How to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to put the INSERT statements into a post deployment script.